# singletons and google coding-style

Tags: coding-style, singleton

Google c++ coding-style does not allow non-trivial static objects (and for a reason) and hence no singletons. At the same time singletons do represent reality of application logic.

So what is the correct way to implement singleton functionality google-style:
(a) have static pointers and initialize them on startup as a separate step (e.g. by linked list of initializer/maker classes)
(b) have context holding references to all singleton-like object and pass it with every method 
(c) have context to be member of every class
(d) something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "[Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html)" does mention "Types representing singleton objects (**`Registerer`**)"

You can see an implementation of said registerer in [`ronaflx/cpp-utility`](https://github.com/ronaflx/cpp-utility) with "[`util/registerer.h`](https://github.com/ronaflx/cpp-utility/blob/f88c0cedb07348275d60d95c278d208f73a7f655/util/registerer.h)" for function pointers ([illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25489310/6309)), and [`util/singleton.h`](https://github.com/ronaflx/cpp-utility/blob/f88c0cedb07348275d60d95c278d208f73a7f655/util/singleton.h) for classic singleton.

The OP points to their own project [`alex4747-pub/proper_singleton`](https://github.com/alex4747-pub/proper_singleton).

Comment: So the actual answer is (a): use static pointers  to avoid dealing with destruction issues.

Comment: FYI: I had ust typed in sample code to express (a) approach: https://github.com/alex4747-pub/proper_singleton

Comment: @zzz777 Thank you. I have included your repository in the answer for more visibility.