# Why does this code give the error, "template specialization requires 'template<>'"?

Tags: c++, templates, clang, template-specialization, crtp

When I try to compile this with Clang

```
template<class T>
struct Field
{
    char const *name;
    Field(char const *name) : name(name) { }
};

template<class Derived>
class CRTP { static Field<Derived> const _field; };

class Class : public CRTP<Class> { };
Field<Class>   const CRTP<Class>::_field("blah");

int main() { }
```

I get

```
error: template specialization requires 'template<>'
Field<Class>   const CRTP<Class>::_field("blah");
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
```

I don't understand the error at all. What is wrong with my definition of `_field` and how do I fix it?

(Note that the arguments to `_field` are not necessarily the same for all subclasses.)

Comment: Have you tried prepending template<>?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: Haha no, I don't understand what this has to do with specialization at all, since I wasn't specializing anything... didn't really occur to me to go in that direction.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Well, actually you are specializing the `static` data member of your class template for the `Class` class (per 17.4.3/1 `static` data members can be specialized, just like member functions)

Comment: @AndyProwl: Ahh... I didn't know you could specialize a single member, I thought you could only specialize a class/function. Cool, thanks!

Comment: @Mehrdad: Only `static` data members though ;)

Comment: @Mehrdad Read clang error messages as literally as possible...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the compiler to identify this as a template specialization (e.g. to be able to check the syntax), you need the `template` keyword:

```
template<>
Field<Class> const CRTP<Class>::_field("blah");
```

Its brackets are empty as all template parameters are specialized, but you cannot just leave it away.

Answer (score 3):

The error says exactly what is missing.  `template<>` is missing before that line.

```
template<>
Field<Class> const CRTP<Class>::_field("blah");
```

Note, however, that your typing of `Field<Class>`, if unique, could be used to construct all instances of `Field<Class>` with a given string.

```
template<typename T>
struct field_trait;

template<class T>
struct Field
{
    char const *name;
    Field() : name(field_trait<T>::get_name()) {}
};

template<class Derived>
class CRTP { static Field<Derived> const _field; };
template<class Derived>
class CRTP<Derived>::_field;

class Class;

template<>
struct field_traits<Class> {
  static const char* get_name() { return "blah"; }
};

class Class : public CRTP<Class> { };

int main() { }
```

which means that every instance of `Field<Class>` always has the name `"blah"`.

One question I would have is, do you really need storage for said `Field<Class>` to actually have a pointer to a string, and if so does it need to be unique, and if so does it need to be "bare"?  Because figuring out where the `static` instance exists is somewhat annoying.

Together with `field_traits` above:

```
template<class Derived>
class CRTP { static Field<Derived>& field() const { static Field<Derived> _field( field_traits<Derived>::get_name()); return _field; };
```

this moves the problem of "where is the `_field` stored" to being the compilers problem.  And it is initialized by the contents of `field_traits<T>::get_name()`.

Comment: No, I really *do* need it to be a static field like that. You might want to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1310392/541686) for an example of where it is necessary (factory registration is one of them).

Answer (score 3):

A static data member must have both a declaration and a definition. If this was a plain class it would look like this:

```
// header:
class C {
    static int i;
};

// source:
int C::i = 3;
```

Templates aren't ordinarily defined in source files, so the code would look something like this:

```
// header:
template <class T>
class C {
    static int i;
};

template <class T>
int C<T>::i = 3;
```

In your code, you don't have the definition of the static data member. That's okay if you don't use it. But the code that the compiler is complaining about defines a static data member for `CRTP<Class>`; that's a specialization (because it's not applicable to all instantiations of `CRTP`, just to this one), and the compiler is saying that you have to tell it that it's a specialization. So do as you're told:

```
template <>
Field<Class> const CRTP<Class>::_field("blah");
```

or, to write the non-specialized template version, use the usual template syntax:

```
template <class T>
Field<T> const CRTP<T>::_field("blah");
```